# What is the range of optical flow in an image?

Tags: opencv, pytorch, opticalflow

I use opencv to calculate optical flow between 2 images (frame_t and frame_t+1). Then I want to use optical flow to warp frame t to get warped_frame_t+1. The warping function is F.grid_sample (pytorch). Since the range of grid in F.grid_sample is (-1,1), I need to normalize optical flow. But How should I do the normalization? What is the range of optical flow in an image? Is it in the range of (-w+1,w-1) (-h+1,h-1)?

Answer (score 0):

np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,W), np.linspace(-1,1,H))